# script/cibuild: Permission denied when building with Jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I'm getting the following error when building with Jenkins:

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/test-1b8ac945ebc2383345391847605819c5/workspace
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson5014904737097448499.sh
+ [ ! -d ./.git ]
+ git fetch -q origin
+ git reset -q --hard a3ff7b59246560719bc3a8f2e89f0b5720fa32c3
+ [ -f script/cibuild ]
+ script/cibuild
/tmp/hudson5014904737097448499.sh: 9: /tmp/hudson5014904737097448499.sh: script/cibuild: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The configuration script is the janky default:

```
if [ ! -d "./.git" ]; then
  git init
  git remote add origin git@github.com:repo/my_repo
fi
git fetch -q origin
git reset -q --hard $JANKY_SHA1
if [ -f script/cibuild ]; then
  script/cibuild
else
  bundle install --path vendor/gems --binstubs
  bundle exec rake
fi
```

I've created my own script/cibuild, but from the error, it doesn't look like it has the correct permissions. How can permissions on this be set correctly automatically from Jenkins? The file itself is stored in the repo, so I don't want to have to login Jenkins and set permissions every time.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To solve, I added `chmod 700 script/cibuild` if the script/cibuild exists. For this change to be global in Janky, you need to edit the config/default.xml.erb in the Janky folder

```
if [ ! -d "./.git" ]; then
  git init
  git remote add origin git@github.com:repo/my_repo
fi
git fetch -q origin
git reset -q --hard $JANKY_SHA1
if [ -f script/cibuild ]; then
  chmod 700 script/cibuild
  script/cibuild
else
  bundle install --path vendor/gems --binstubs
  bundle exec rake
fi
```